# PyCharm, how to skip autocomplete suggestions

Tags: python, pycharm

I like the autocomplete feature of PyCharm in most cases. But sometimes it just suggests nonsense.
For example if I want to name a method `one` it renames it to `__round__(self, n=None)`

How can I skip the suggestion in this case? I didn't find the correct keyword in the PyCharm documentation.

If I write eg. `def one` I would prefer the following behaviour:

- `tab` or/and `enter` --> accept suggestion
- `shift + ctrl + enter` --> complete statement to `def one(self):`

Answer (score 2):

You can press the Esc key to reject the suggestion, per the documentation.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html

Comment: Not the most ergonomic choice, frankly. If anyone knows how to configure that differently, please update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion

UNCHECK - Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys

Now, you can use SPACE to skip.
TAB or RETURN will insert.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can tap `space` when the autocomplete suggestion appears and then delete the space instead of using Mouse.

It works for the first time pycharm shows suggestion, but if you use `ctrl+space` for suggstion and then tapping `space`, it will autocomplete default code suggestion.

Anyway, `space` is enough for preventing coding interruption